# Assign an id to different points with the same coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, database, geospatial, geopandas

I have a dataset that contains multipoint, each point has associated data such as name, location etc. However, several of those points have the same geographic coordinate (x and y), but currently they are responding to a different index:

| Current Index | Name | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj | 0,608467 | 41,615444 |
| 2 | Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj | 0,610446 | 41,615462 |
| 3 | Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj | 0,610446 | 41,615462 |
| 4 | Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj | 0,610446 | 41,615462 |

How can I find the duplicates in both x and y (in my example 2, 3 and 4) and assign the same index to those without having to delete them as well:

| NewIndex | Name | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj | 0,608467 | 41,615444 |
| 2 | Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj | 0,610446 | 41,615462 |
| 2 | Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj | 0,610446 | 41,615462 |
| 2 | Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj | 0,610446 | 41,615462 |

Comment: You should see what you need. If you don't need other columns, you can simply do this by deleting other rows and keeping just one. If not, you can use array of other columns' values. It's up to you!

Comment: I need to keep all the values, but I need to identify which attributes correspond to the same point.

Comment: So what would happen to other columns? What you wanna use as the value of `name` column for those with same coordinate?

Comment: Some points although they have the same coordinate have different names, and as in the example some with the same name have different coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I think `groupby` and `ngroup` is what you need

```
import pandas as pd

#make the df in the example
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Current Index': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
     'Name': {0: 'Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj',
      1: 'Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj',
      2: 'Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj',
      3: 'Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj'},
     'x': {0: '0,608467', 1: '0,610446', 2: '0,610446', 3: '0,610446'},
     'y': {0: '41,615444', 1: '41,615462', 2: '41,615462', 3: '41,615462'}
})

#number the groups
df['New Index'] = df.groupby(['x','y']).ngroup()+1
df
```

Output

```
   Current Index                  Name         x          y  New Index
0              1  Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj  0,608467  41,615444          1
1              2  Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj  0,610446  41,615462          2
2              3  Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj  0,610446  41,615462          2
3              4  Ko04OrnPu_5TanXsA7Dj  0,610446  41,615462          2
```